# can't define condition

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

im trying to define the condition `SR.PRODUCT_STOCK2 > 0` inside the sql code, since it `AS` of sum condition, here is the sql code

```
    SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,PR.PRICE,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD
<cfif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
    ,(SUM(SR.STOCK_IN)-SUM(SR.STOCK_OUT)) AS PRODUCT_STOCK2
</cfif>
FROM PRODUCT P
    JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
    JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
    JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.GET_STOCK_LAST GSL ON P.PRODUCT_ID = GSL.PRODUCT_ID
    <cfif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
        JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.STOCKS_ROW SR ON P.PRODUCT_ID=SR.PRODUCT_ID
    </cfif>
WHERE PS.PURCHASESALES=1 AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1 AND P.IS_SALES=1 AND P.IS_PURCHASE=1 AND P.IS_INTERNET=1 AND P.IS_EXTRANET=1
<cfif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
    AND
        (
        <cfloop list="#attributes.department_id#" delimiters="," index="dept_i">
        (SR.STORE = #listfirst(dept_i,'-')# AND SR.STORE_LOCATION = #listlast(dept_i,'-')#)
        <cfif dept_i neq listlast(attributes.department_id,',') and listlen(attributes.department_id,',') gte 1> OR</cfif>
        </cfloop>  
        )
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.is_stock') and attributes.is_stock is 1>
            AND SR.PRODUCT_STOCK2 > 0
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,PR.PRICE,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD
```

the error log says: Invalid column name `PRODUCT_STOCK2` i know that i wrongly defined the condition, i just don't know how to define it right, need help! Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to use a having clause like so:

```
HAVING (SUM(SR.STOCK_IN)-SUM(SR.STOCK_OUT)) > 0
```

Comment: What does your new query look like?

Comment: everything is the same except instead of `AND SR.PRODUCT_STOCK2 > 0` the `HAVING (SUM(SR.STOCK_IN)-SUM(SR.STOCK_OUT)) > 0`

Comment: Having needs to be after the Group by clause. So you query will end like this: GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,PR.PRICE,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD HAVING (SUM(SR.STOCK_IN)-SUM(SR.STOCK_OUT)) > 0

Comment: THANK YOU :) i wrote that kind of sql code but don't know the basics ))